# Add Custom Metadata to Already-defined ItemGroup from Another ItemGroup

Tags: msbuild

I have the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Files Include="C:\Versioning\**\file.version" />
<ItemGroup>

<ReadLinesFromFile File="%(Files.Identity)">
  <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="_Version"/>
</ReadLinesFromFile>
```

where each file.version file contains simply one line which is - you guessed it - a version of the form `Major.Minor.Build.Revision`.

I want to be able to associate each item in the `Files` ItemGroup with its `_Version` by adding the latter as metadata, so that I can do something like:

```
<Message Text="%(Files.Identity): %(Files.Version)" />
```

and have MSBuild print out a nice list of file-version associations.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be achieved by using target batching to add your `Version` member to the metadata. This involves moving your `ReadLinesFromFile` operation to its own target, using the `@(Files)` ItemGroup as an input.

This causes the target to be executed for each item in your ItemGroup, allowing you to read the contents (i.e. version number) from each individual file and subsequently update that item to add the `Version` metadata:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="OutputFilesAndVersions" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Files Include="C:\Versioning\**\file.version" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="OutputFilesAndVersions" DependsOnTargets="RetrieveVersions">
        <Message Text="@(Files->'%(Identity): %(Version)')" />
    </Target>
    <Target Name="RetrieveVersions" Inputs="@(Files)" Outputs="%(Files.Identity)">
        <ReadLinesFromFile File="%(Files.Identity)">
          <Output TaskParameter="Lines" PropertyName="_Version"/>
        </ReadLinesFromFile>
        <PropertyGroup>
            <MyFileName>%(Files.Identity)</MyFileName>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <ItemGroup>
            <Files Condition="'%(Files.Identity)'=='$(MyFileName)'">
                <Version>$(_Version)</Version>
            </Files>
        </ItemGroup>  
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I came up with as well. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielNolan - would you please add some explanation to this answer to help people learn about Target batching and why this answer works? Some of us need a gentle reminder, others need a short tutorial

Comment: @JJS thanks for the feedback. I have added an explanation to the beginning of my answer.

Comment: Please correct the `@Files` item reference to `@(Files)` in the text as well as in the example.