# How to get MSBuild output parameter for each execution of a batched task?

Tags: msbuild

I have an MSBuild target that runs an Exec task on several items. How do I get the exit code for each of them?

I can use this to get all the exit codes and to run only if the input files have changed since the last run (i.e. incremental builds):

```
<ItemGroup>
    <TestItem Include="MyFile1" />
    <TestItem Include="MyFile2" />
    <TestItem Include="MyFile10" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="PrepareItemTest">
    <ItemGroup>
        <TestItem>
            <!-- The timestamp of the "done file" is used below to detect if this target has been run since the inputs have been modified. -->
            <DoneFilePath>%(TestItem.RelativeDir)%(TestItem.Filename).done/DoneFilePath>
        </TestItem>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>

<Target Name="ItemTest"
      DependsOnTargets="PrepareItemTest"
      Inputs="@(TestItem);@(OtherInputs)"
      Outputs="%(TestItem.DoneFilePath)">

    <Exec Command="ECHO Running on %(TestItem.Identity) |findstr 1" IgnoreExitCode="true">
        <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="TestExitCode"/>
    </Exec>

    <Error Condition=" '$(TestExitCode)' != '0' " Text="Error $TestExitCode" />
    <WriteLinesToFile Condition=" '$(TestExitCode)' == '0' " File="%(TestItem.DoneFilePath)" Lines="Ran successfully on %(TestItem.Filename)%(TestItem.Extension)" />
</Target>
```

Output:

```
Ran ItemTest. Exit code=0
Ran ItemTest. Exit code=1
```

So this prints all the different exit codes returned, but it doesn't associate them with the input item, so I don't know which inputs were processed successfully and which were not.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420812/add-custom-metadata-to-already-defined-itemgroup-from-another-itemgroup for instance, that does exactly wht you want (just uses ReadLines to get output instead of exexe, but the principle is the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to [batch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171473.aspx) over the *target* rather than the task itself.  That effectively "moves the loop up a level", from (pseudocode):

```
target PrepareItemTest {
    foreach item in TestItem {
        TestExitCode.append(exec().result))
    }
    warn("exit codes: " + TestExitCode)
}
```

to

```
target PrepareItemTest {
    foreach item in TestItem {
        TestExitCode.append(exec().result))
        warn("exit code: " item + " " + TestExitCode)
    }
}
```

If the items represent files that produce outputs, this is straightforward and you should batch in the `Inputs` attribute (and define `Outputs` for correct incremental behaviors).

For the example you've given, it's slightly confusing, because the target is not producing a set of output files. That means you have to misuse the target's `Outputs` attribute to get the batching behavior. You can do:

```
<Target Name="ItemTest" Outputs="%(TestItem.Identity)">
    <Exec Command="ECHO Running on @(TestItem->'%(Identity)') |findstr 1" IgnoreExitCode="true">
        <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="TestExitCode"/>
    </Exec>

    <Warning Text="Ran ItemTest for @(TestItem). Exit code=$(TestExitCode)" />
</Target>
```

Which produces

```
Project "D:\work\batch-over-target.proj" on node 1 (default targets).
ItemTest:
  ECHO Running on MyItem1 |findstr 1
  Running on MyItem1
D:\work\batch-over-target.proj(14,5): warning : Ran ItemTest for MyItem1. Exit code=0
ItemTest:
  ECHO Running on MyItem2 |findstr 1
  The command "ECHO Running on MyItem2 |findstr 1" exited with code 1.
D:\work\batch-over-target.proj(14,5): warning : Ran ItemTest for MyItem2. Exit code=1
ItemTest:
  ECHO Running on MyItem10 |findstr 1
  Running on MyItem10
D:\work\batch-over-target.proj(14,5): warning : Ran ItemTest for MyItem10. Exit code=0
Done Building Project "D:\work\batch-over-target.proj" (default targets).
```

The reason this works is that within a batch, an item accessed with `@(ItemName)` includes *only the results that fit in the batch*.  If you are careful to make sure that each batch is only one item, you can correlate outputs with inputs.

Comment: So basically it's just a matter of adding `Outputs="%(TestItem.Identity)"` ? That's a nice trick, thank you! The only problem is that my real target already has Output set to enable incremental building, so I suppose I'd have to put the Exec task into a sub-target and call that using an MSBuild task.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using an MSBuild task in this situation, because to be able to invoke it multiple times you'd have to change global properties which is dangerous. You should be able to avoid it, though. Can you update the question to make the target look a bit more like your real one? I bet there's a way to make it work all together.

Comment: OK, I've edited the question. Basically I want to support incremental builds by only running the Exec task when the output is older than the input. I write a one-line text file at the end of the target, which acts as the "output".

Comment: You can almost get that behavior for free--see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171483.aspx. The wrinkle is your `@(OtherInputs)`, which throw off the 1:1 relationship between inputs and outputs. But I'm not quite sure how that relates to the edited question--is what you're `Exec`ing an up-to-date check?

Comment: No, the Exec is the real build. It runs grunt, actually. @(OtherInputs) are all the inputs to the grunt build. Of course, the grunt build has real output files, but since they're a bit hard to keep track of I went with the easier option of just "touching" a special file whenever the build runs and checking that file.

Comment: Ah, now I understand! In that case, your target definition looks good--all of the inputs are defined, and batch over the output marker file. To have a collection of "what had to run", you could add an `<ItemGroup>` into the target and create a new item that `Include`s the `TestItem` and has metadata based on the process exit code. Then you could look at that later.