# Output items from msbuild custom target

Tags: msbuild, .net-core

After spending the whole day studying MsBuild: project files, items, properties, targets and tasks, I still cannot find a solution for my problem.

I aim to create a custom target in my .csproj to generate binary files from input text files using console program. The target does what it should do. But I want the generated files to be part of the project file as Content that should be copied (published) together with an application.

I ended up the the following project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <MyTool>.\tools\mytool.exe</MyTool>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="MyTarget" DependsOnTargets="Restore" BeforeTargets="Build;Publish"
      Inputs="@(TxtFiles)"
      Outputs="@(TxtFiles->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).bin')">
    <Exec Command="$(MyTool) -o %(TxtFiles.RootDir)%(TxtFiles.Directory)%(TxtFiles.Filename).bin %(TxtFiles.Identity)"
      Outputs="@(TxtFiles->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).bin')">
      <Output TaskParameter="Outputs" ItemName="BinFiles" />
    </Exec>
  </Target>
  <ItemGroup>
    <TxtFiles Include="my_resources\*.txt" />
    <Content Include="@(TxtFiles)">
       <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="@(BinFiles)">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <PublishState>Included</PublishState>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Unfortunately - it doesn't populate item `@(BinFiles)`.
If if declate it manually (as if calling the tool beforehand), it works:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="my_resources\*.bin">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    <PublishState>Included</PublishState>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

I want to achieve the same behavior. Also as my target declares inputs and outputs, how whould it populate its outputs to be added as content?

Comment: For the item group that does work: does it work if you put it inside the target?. Also, use BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild;PrepareForPublish"

Comment: If I declare the same ItemGroup inside my target. The files are copied to Output dir even if the target wasn't executed (due to Inputs and Outputs). But I declared it statically (as in question), because I cannot use @Item in "Include". Also I changed as you suggested to "BeforeBuild;PrepareForPublish".

Comment: oh I missed that the item group is not inside your `<Target>`. it needs to be inside it to run after the task creates the `@(BinFiles)`. static content is evaluated before any target is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the other question had a clue in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7425166/4758517).
Using it managed to define the final project file which worked as intended. I understood that I do not need the target Outputs, but rather add them to the Contents item.

I ended up with the following:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <MyTool>.\tools\mytool.exe</MyTool>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="my_resources\**\*.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="MyTarget" DependsOnTargets="Restore" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild;PrepareForPublish">
    <ItemGroup>
      <TxtFiles Include="@(Content)" Condition="'%(Extension)' == '.txt'" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Exec Command="$(MyTool) -o $([System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension('%(TxtFiles.Fullpath)','.bin')) %(TxtFiles.Identity)"
       Outputs="$([System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension('%(TxtFiles.Fullpath)','.bin'))">
      <Output TaskParameter="Outputs" ItemName="_BinFiles" />
    </Exec>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="@(_BinFiles)">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        <PublishState>Included</PublishState>
      </Content>
      <BinFiles Include="@(Content)" Condition="'%(Extension)' == '.bin'" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```